# Alarm Manager status after force closing the app by OS due to low memory

Tags: android

I want to know what happens with the alarm manager if Android itself killed the app due to very low memory. Would your alarms be lost in this case? How often does this actually happen?
How to recover or restart the alarm manager?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Your alarm will not be lost in case of force closing.It can be lost if the device is powered off.For details [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)